# Lets Encrypt Azure Error "No Web App Could Be Found"

Tags: azure, lets-encrypt

I have followed this article to the letter: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SecuringAnAzureAppServiceWebsiteUnderSSLInMinutesWithLetsEncrypt.aspx

In summary, I:

1. Created an application registration.
2. Added the registration as a contributor to an a resource group
3. Verified that my app service under that resource group is "Always On"
4. Double, Triple, Quadruple checked that the resource group names, and Ids are accurate in the form below:

[image: Configuring LetsEncrypt Azure Site Extension]

*Please note that in the image above it appears that Tenant, SubscriptionID, ClientID, and ClientSecret appear not filled in. They are, but just redacted from the image*

Googling this phenomenon has not rendered many results, which puzzles me considering how many seem to have success with this extension and using LetsEncrypt with Azure.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The SiteSlot name should be left blank.
if you fill in the SiteSlot name then the script will look for a resrouce group with a web app with that siteslot name.  A siteslot is a deployment slot.  If you just spun up an app with no deployment slots or you want your cert on teh default slot then please leave this blank.

Comment: Can you update your answer to be more clear. Can you say "The SiteSlotName should be left blank" if that's the intention. And explain briefly why do you think so. As you can see from the shared image it is blank. The steps in the tutorial also have it blank so that's probably not the problem, unless it has an empty space or something

Comment: I understand that this is not the OP's problem, but this did indeed solve mine!